# Non json output from gcloud ai-platform predict. Parsing non-json outputs

Tags: json, google-api, google-ai-platform

I am using `gcloud ai-platform predict` to call an endpoint and get predictions as below using `json-request` and not `json-response`

```
gcloud ai-platform predict --json-request instances.json
```

The response is however not `json` and hense cannot be read further causing other complications. Below is the response.

```
VAL  HS
0.5  {'hs_1': [[-0.134501, -0.307326, -0.151994, -0.065352,  -0.14138]], 'hs_2' : [[-0.134501, -0.307326, -0.151994, -0.065352, 0.020759]]}
```

Can `gcloud ai-platform predict` return a `json` instead or may be parse it differently. ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could check with whatever API that you are using, if it can return the result in a proper JSON format? The one you posted is not

Comment: This is indeed not JSON. If you remove everything before (and not including) the opening curly brace `{` and enclose the field names with `"` instead of `'` like so `"lstm_1"` and `"lstm_2"`, it will become proper JSON.

Comment: Yes its not a json that the api is sending as response. I changed the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, your output is a table with headers and two columns: a score and the (alleged) JSON content. You should extract the second column of any preferred data row (your example only has one but in general you might receive several score-JSON pairs). Maybe your API already offers functionality to extract a certain 'state', e.g. the one with the highest score. If not, a simple `awk` or `sed` script can get this job done easily.

Then, the only remaining issue before having proper JSON (which can then be queried by `jq`) is with the quoting style. Your output encloses field names with `'` instead of `"` (`'lstm_1'` instead of `"lstm_1"`). Correcting thin, unfortunately, is a not-so-easy task if you can expect to receive arbitrarily complex JSON data (such as strings containing quotation marks etc.). However, if your JSON will always look as *simple* as in the example provided, simply substituting the wrong for the right one becomes an easy task again for tools like `awk` or `sed`.

For instance, using `sed` on your example output to select the second line (which is the first data row), drop everything from the beginning until but not including the first opening curly brace (which marks the beginning of the second column), make said substitutions and pipe the result into `jq`:

```sh
... | sed -n "2{s/^[^{]\+//;s/'/\"/g;p;q}" | jq .
```

```json
{
  "lstm_1": [
    [
      -0.13450142741203308,
      -0.3073260486125946,
      -0.15199440717697144,
      -0.06535257399082184,
      -0.1413831114768982
    ]
  ],
  "lstm_2": [
    [
      -0.13450142741203308,
      -0.3073260486125946,
      -0.15199440717697144,
      -0.06535257399082184,
      0.02075939252972603
    ]
  ]
}
```

---

[Edited to reflect upon a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69882785/non-json-output-from-gcloud-ai-platform-predict/69885126?noredirect=1#comment123537242_69885126)]

If you want to utilize the score as well, let `jq` handle it. For instance:

```sh
... | sed -n "2{s/'/\"/g;p;q}" | jq -s '{score:first,status:last}'
```

```json
{
  "score": 0.548,
  "status": {
    "lstm_1": [
      [
        -0.13450142741203308,
        -0.3073260486125946,
        -0.15199440717697144,
        -0.06535257399082184,
        -0.1413831114768982
      ]
    ],
    "lstm_2": [
      [
        -0.13450142741203308,
        -0.3073260486125946,
        -0.15199440717697144,
        -0.06535257399082184,
        0.02075939252972603
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

---

[Edited to reflect upon changes in the OP]

As changes affected only names and values but no structure, the hitherto valid approach still holds:

```sh
... | sed -n "2{s/'/\"/g;p;q}" | jq -s '{val:first,hs:last}'
```

```json
{
  "val": 0.5,
  "hs": {
    "hs_1": [
      [
        -0.134501,
        -0.307326,
        -0.151994,
        -0.065352,
        -0.14138
      ]
    ],
    "hs_2": [
      [
        -0.134501,
        -0.307326,
        -0.151994,
        -0.065352,
        0.020759
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: hm may be. But in a similar way should get the score too.

Comment: Then let `jq` handle the columns. See my edit.

Comment: changed the question to reflect the problem. can u edit your answer too.

Comment: According to [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69882785/revisions) you changed the table column headers from `SCORE` and `STATES` to `VAL` and `HS`, the (alleged) JSON's field names from `lstm_1` and `lstm_2` to `hs_1` and `hs_2`, and the actual numeric values. Structurally, however, nothing has changed. You still need to parse the same table, and the second column's data still lacks proper JSON quotation. I can't help you with making Google API deliver proper JSON, but I can (and did) help you with parsing what you received, which is structurally the same as before your edit.